# Appcelerator - iOS module invalid method

Tags: javascript, ios, module, appcelerator-alloy

I'm trying to learn how to create an iOS module for appcelerator alloy using this tutorial in the [documentation here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/iOS_Module_Quick_Start).

I followed every step as described. But whenever I try to call createView from my module. It gives me the following error:

```
"invalid method (createView) passed to ComExampleTestModule";
```

I can't even set a property as shown in the tutorial.

Why is this happening? I know I'm missing something here. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is more likely to be answered were you to add the code you used in JS to call the module, and your module code.

Comment: @StephenFeather I've used the same exact code mentioned in the example link I'm following.